# How to reshape table for ANOVA?

Tags: r

I have a large table with multiple columns, each column being one different model. 
In the rows are the different results of these models at a specific location on a map.

See picture (I had to change the column names)...

[image]

Now, I want to check with an ANOVA in R if there is a signifanct difference between the results at every location between the different models. In other words: If the models are responsible for a difference, if there is any.
I am not 100% sure an ANOVA is the best way to go, but I want to try.

How can I reshape my table to long format (is it?)
I tried with "gather" (tidyr) but I am not sure what the inputs are.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A friend helped me. A simple `stack(data)` did the trick!